# Walking Parent/Child relation tree upwards

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, parent-child, navigation-properties

I've got a folder structure represented as a parent / child relation tree. Now let's imagine the following tree:

> -- Folder1
>
> --- Subfolder1-1
>
> ---- Subfolder1-1-1
>
> --- Subfolder2
>
> ---- Subfolder2-1
>
> -- Folder2

Now I obviously got navigation properties to use, so when inside `Subfolder1-1` I got a property `ParentFolder` that represents `Folder1`.

How can I now walk up the tree to generate a concatenated string out of the folder names?

For example when calling this method from `Subfolder1-1-1`, I want the string to be `Folder1.Subfolder1-1.Subfolder1-1-1` and when calling from `Subfolder2-1`, I want the string to be `Folder1.Subfolder2.Subfolder2-1`.

I've thought about recursion, but the following did not work:

```
public string GetCompleteFolderName(string delimiter)
{
    string folderName = null;

    if (FolderParent != null)
    {
        folderName += GetCompleteFolderName(FolderParent) + delimiter;
    }

    return folderName;
}

private string GetCompleteFolderName(Folder folder)
{
    string folderName = null;
    if (folder != null)
    {
        folderName = folder.Name;
    }

    return folderName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should do the trick

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Folder()
    {
    }
    public string GetFullFolderName(string delimiter = ".")
    {
        var folderName = string.Empty;
        if (ParentFolder != null)
        {
            folderName += ParentFolder.GetFullFolderName(delimiter) + delimiter + Name;
        }
        else
        {
            folderName += Name;
        }
        return folderName;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f1 = new Folder {Name = "f1"};
        var f2 = new Folder {Name = "f2", ParentFolder = f1};
        var f3 = new Folder {Name = "f3", ParentFolder = f2};

        Console.WriteLine(f3.GetFullFolderName());
    }
}
```

outputs: f1.f2.f3

Comment: Just what I wanted. Congratulations to your first reputation and thank you!